# How to make ggplot colors more distinct and colorblind friendly?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
toLonger <- function(expressionMatrix) {
    expressionMatrix <- longExpressionMatrix <- expressionMatrix %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column("gene") %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = !gene, 
                 values_to = "Expression",
                 names_to = "sample_id") 
  return(expressionMatrix)
}

toLonger(dge_cpmlogtwo)  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Expression, color = sample_id)) +
  geom_density() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

I want to make the colors in the third last line stand out more?  I found this reply but was not able to understand how to apply it to my code.

Lastly is there a way to ensure my plots will be color blind frinedly?

Comment: Packages [`viridis`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/index.html) and [`viridisLite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridisLite/index.html) both target palettes for various types of color blindness. In my experience with reports and apps (both R), it can be difficult to be perfectly immune, since some people are truly colorblind and the palette alone may be insufficient, in which case one would need to revert to linetype or diag-lines/patterns (fill). How much you do depends on the actual needs of the audience.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding colorblind friendly palettes, you could consult these two links which address the issue:

1. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html
2. https://colorbrewer2.org/
3. http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/

I don't have access to your data, but you should be able to click around to find a palette you like, and apply it to your ggplot with the info linked above, good luck!

Here's an example of how it might apply to your case:

```r
toLonger(dge_cpmlogtwo)  %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Expression, color = sample_id)) +
    geom_density() +
    scale_color_brewer(palette="BrBG") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Also it is aparently not very clear how to find the palette codes in question, eg `BrBG`, but one way would be like this:

1. Choose a palette you like from colorbrewer2.org
2. check the URL for which code it has
3. Use this code with the `palette=` argument for eg. `scale_color_brewer` , like I have done above.

See this image to see what I mean, on it I have the cookbook-r.com and colorbrewer2.org pages from above opened in two windows. Red rectangular highlight is added by me:

[image: detail from relevant web pages]