How to visualise the relative values of 3 parameters with a color-blind friendly colors in a single figure?
I have a dataframe df with the coordinates x and y, and 3 other variables: a, b, and c (please, see below for reproducible data):
library(tidyverse)

head(df)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
      x     y         a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 -73.5 -40.5 0         0.560 0.440
2 -72.5 -40.5 0.0000947 0.597 0.403
3 -70.5 -40.5 0.00696   0.563 0.430
4 -69.5 -40.5 0.0138    0.513 0.473
5 -68.5 -40.5 0.00644   0.633 0.360
6 -67.5 -40.5 0.00200   0.653 0.345

The parameters a, b, and c are relative contribution values of each corresponding parameter and they add to 1. I want to visualise the data in a single plot using ggplot2 with a color-blind friendly colors.
What I have tried so far: I asked this question previously and got an excellent answer. Whit this answer I can do:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtern)
library(patchwork)

main_plot <- df %>%
        mutate(col = rgb(a, b, c)) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
        geom_tile(aes(fill = col), color = NA) +
        scale_fill_identity() +
        coord_equal() +
        theme_minimal()

df2 <- expand.grid(a = seq(0, 1, 0.01), b = seq(0, 1, 0.01), c = seq(0, 1, 0.01))
df2 <- df2[rowSums(df2) == 1,]
df2$rgb <- rgb(df2$a, df2$b, df2$c)

legend_plot <- ggtern(df2, aes(a, b, z = c, color = rgb)) +
        geom_point() +
        scale_color_identity() +
        scale_L_continuous(labels = function(x) character(length(x))) +
        ggtitle("Relative values") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
              axis.text = element_blank())

main_plot + 
        wrap_elements(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(legend_plot))) +
        plot_layout(design = "AAAA#
                        AAAAB
                        AAAA#")

which produces:

However, when I used this approach, I got critisized that the figure is not very informative for people with color deficiencies (color-blindness).
How can I make this plot more color-blind friendly? E.g. instead of using red, green and blue, I would like to use orange (#E69F00), sky-blue (#56B4E9) and bluish-green (#009E73).
Reproducible data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(x = c(-73.5, -72.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, 
-66.5, -65.5, -64.5, -63.5, -73.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, 
-66.5, -65.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -65.5, -70.5, 
-69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -65.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, 
-67.5, -66.5, -73.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -74.5, 
-70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, 
-71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -74.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, 
-68.5, -74.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -72.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, 
-71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -69.5), y = c(-40.5, 
-40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, 
-41.5, -41.5, -41.5, -41.5, -41.5, -41.5, -41.5, -42.5, -42.5, 
-42.5, -42.5, -42.5, -42.5, -43.5, -43.5, -43.5, -43.5, -43.5, 
-43.5, -44.5, -44.5, -44.5, -44.5, -44.5, -44.5, -45.5, -45.5, 
-45.5, -45.5, -45.5, -45.5, -46.5, -46.5, -46.5, -46.5, -46.5, 
-47.5, -47.5, -47.5, -47.5, -47.5, -48.5, -48.5, -48.5, -48.5, 
-48.5, -49.5, -49.5, -49.5, -49.5, -49.5, -50.5, -50.5, -50.5, 
-50.5, -51.5, -51.5, -51.5, -51.5, -52.5, -52.5, -52.5, -53.5, 
-53.5, -54.5, -55.5), a = c(0, 9.46581738186483e-05, 0.00696497150559271, 
0.0137849902303819, 0.00643740569455534, 0.00199816358740475, 
0, 0, 0, 5.06412179534512e-05, 0, 0.0398551254689963, 0.0310856391742892, 
0.0195084547186265, 0.00122115866765995, 0.000262981842424393, 
0.000728947548683327, 0.0180714589486645, 0.0217375647896753, 
0.0302549061176794, 0.0121843041040885, 0.000681282606889494, 
4.35093747206288e-05, 0.0529538781527676, 0.0273285713315873, 
0.0110374092101145, 0.00537239572379284, 0.00472400342189244, 
0.00147365976111469, 0.0259683795649571, 0.0463436806229692, 
0.0267969428070688, 0.020294577628928, 0.00821922974468169, 0.00233230625628307, 
0.00387696973516025, 0.0514313688652839, 0.0645759934429092, 
0.0239569529899347, 0.027534701081013, 0.00534849512202001, 0.00128844338962426, 
0.0426685507779651, 0.0284580643386483, 0.00971006844234354, 
0.00420984206165692, 0.053985050339934, 0.0583984918343995, 0.0172826529268439, 
0.0121423976240239, 0.00547793750320507, 0.0585686295112969, 
0.0340311779773938, 0.0311015513254945, 0.0200707300297805, 0.00957150788475225, 
0.00361466936278744, 0.0527542952718002, 0.0282832440286811, 
0.0177806525711058, 0.00560265899046886, 0.0024828404080448, 
0.0544720394354926, 0.0186537760879564, 0.0192277515814812, 0.00863003055518693, 
0.0249790371500353, 0.015538215176512, 0.0348873548749255, 0.0206759639364579, 
0.0139234477581141, 0.0205576837132205, 0.0404500818602786, 0.00653946544041233, 
0.0223237332992225, 0.0075707047472664), b = c(0.55973614025667, 
0.5970202227548, 0.563477650463872, 0.513046833650201, 0.633380146860311, 
0.653109185283395, 0.704255523998351, 0.596896242072055, 0.520747918302268, 
0.526828987547501, 0.592212337251761, 0.590540320713732, 0.480335397306457, 
0.631079557708342, 0.6667829974047, 0.64403959660305, 0.591513715061531, 
0.572154253402492, 0.506765134717002, 0.664156380590966, 0.67826734460919, 
0.649022944246854, 0.651215734871819, 0.488798113249405, 0.458045272783363, 
0.693687132763554, 0.700613923064021, 0.751238707050007, 0.712027653396489, 
0.532585134221796, 0.476479299998232, 0.490080331523103, 0.705251451061017, 
0.735714385706559, 0.607922959590343, 0.613134683073939, 0.487692533841504, 
0.548015750900016, 0.509952441369207, 0.74439726199284, 0.690392471171559, 
0.588966236272818, 0.659362140614673, 0.646180042358758, 0.631416450548492, 
0.585094155496678, 0.604202144807992, 0.647823791170224, 0.599329297279972, 
0.725121813884829, 0.650627029395497, 0.542872019089378, 0.65883061118346, 
0.66671626220512, 0.639294598531845, 0.622768680020925, 0.479380596605895, 
0.580708446644663, 0.579879141984736, 0.617496249696512, 0.483541553869077, 
0.474759409900493, 0.42759500296535, 0.444245282360467, 0.491426697536639, 
0.543068445843191, 0.354391820625675, 0.285449114670143, 0.230667732146117, 
0.545516189964805, 0.549909364018411, 0.518094993608081, 0.580561287344482, 
0.591327797599958, 0.52693632685116, 0.64278661995468), c = c(0.44026385974333, 
0.402885119071382, 0.429557378030536, 0.473168176119417, 0.360182447445134, 
0.3448926511292, 0.295744476001649, 0.403103757927945, 0.479252081697732, 
0.473120371234546, 0.407787662748239, 0.369604553817271, 0.488578963519254, 
0.349411987573031, 0.33199584392764, 0.355697421554526, 0.407757337389786, 
0.409774287648843, 0.471497300493323, 0.305588713291354, 0.309548351286721, 
0.350295773146257, 0.34874075575346, 0.458248008597827, 0.514626155885049, 
0.295275458026332, 0.294013681212186, 0.244037289528101, 0.286498686842396, 
0.441446486213247, 0.477177019378799, 0.483122725669829, 0.274453971310055, 
0.256066384548759, 0.389744734153374, 0.3829883471909, 0.460876097293212, 
0.387408255657075, 0.466090605640859, 0.228068036926147, 0.304259033706421, 
0.409745320337558, 0.297969308607362, 0.325361893302593, 0.358873481009164, 
0.410696002441665, 0.341812804852074, 0.293777716995377, 0.383388049793184, 
0.262735788491147, 0.343895033101298, 0.398559351399325, 0.307138210839147, 
0.302182186469385, 0.340634671438375, 0.367659812094323, 0.517004734031317, 
0.366537258083536, 0.391837613986583, 0.364723097732382, 0.510855787140454, 
0.522757749691462, 0.517932957599158, 0.537100941551577, 0.48934555088188, 
0.448301523601622, 0.62062914222429, 0.699012670153345, 0.734444912978957, 
0.433807846098737, 0.436167188223475, 0.461347322678698, 0.37898863079524, 
0.40213273695963, 0.450739939849617, 0.349642675298054)), row.names = c(NA, 
-76L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


Have you looked at the brewer family of scales? Here and here?

Use a custom colour blind friendly palette: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/66748997/680068 and https://r-graph-gallery.com/color-palette-finder

@Limey: thanks a lot for the links. Unfortunately none of them addresses how to combine 3 relative values in in a single map like rgb(), so that we can visualise the contribution of each parameter with their corresponding color contribution

@zx8754 the same (please see above comment, I could not mention you there)

Looks like ggtern has colourblind themes, did you try? theme_bvbw - A black/vermillion/blue theme with white background, for colorblind sensitive readers

As of  R 4.0.0 things have changed: default palettes are good since then. I enjoyed reading https://journal.r-project.org/articles/RJ-2023-071/

@zx8754 in the figure shown in the post, ggtern and ggplot2 plots are 'separate'. The main plot needs its own solution :)

@Friede interesting post, but it does not address the problem described above :)

I first make a matrix with the RGB values for the specified color palette.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtern)
library(patchwork)
library(colorspace)

pal <- c('#E69F00', '#009E73', '#56B4E9')

# Hex to sRGB decimal representation
pal_matrix <- hex2RGB(pal)@coords

rownames(pal_matrix) <- c('orange', 'bluegreen', 'skyblue')
colnames(pal_matrix) <- c('R', 'G', 'B')

pal_matrix
#>                   R         G         B
#> orange    0.9019608 0.6235294 0.0000000
#> bluegreen 0.0000000 0.6196078 0.4509804
#> skyblue   0.3372549 0.7058824 0.9137255

The hex values for each plot are generated after multiplying [a,b,c] by the palette matrix.
main_plot <- cbind(df, as.matrix(df[3:5]) %*% pal_matrix) |>
  mutate(col = rgb(R, G, B)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = col), color = NA) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal()

df2 <- expand.grid(a = seq(0, 1, 0.01), b = seq(0, 1, 0.01), c = seq(0, 1, 0.01))
df2 <- df2[rowSums(df2) == 1,]

legend_plot <- cbind(df2, as.matrix(df2[1:3]) %*% pal_matrix) |>
  mutate(rgb = rgb(R, G, B)) |> 
  ggtern(aes(a, b, z = c, color = rgb)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity() +
  scale_T_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_L_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_R_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  ggtitle("Relative values") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text = element_blank())

main_plot + 
  wrap_elements(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(legend_plot))) +
  plot_layout(design = "AAAA#
                        AAAAB
                        AAAA#")


I'm not convinced this is easier to interpret, but maybe on the full data set or with a different palette?

this looks so promising! can you please show me how you get to the pal_matrix (reproducible example)? You are right, it seems like the colors I chose do not work well with this example. If I know how to get to the matrix, I could try other colors :)

There are a few packages with hex to sRGB decimal conversion functions. I edited to add an example from the colorspace package, where the data is conveniently returned as a matrix in the coords slot of the sRGB object.

thanks! do you know why axis.text = element_blank() does not remove the texts in the legend_plot?

(it works with the original rgb example somehow)

I'm not too familiar with ggtern, but was able to remove the labels/ticks by setting breaks = NULL in the position scales. I've edited the answer to show the legend code and plot with no labels.
